# Object Memory Allocation for a int and tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

[image]

When i check the `id(10)` twice(Object of type int),the interpreter gives the same result result.
But when i try the same with the `tuple object (1,2,3)`, I am getting different answer despite the fact that both int and tuple are immutable. Can i know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Don't post text as image

Answer (score 1):

`int`s have a very special behavior in Python, until 257, no new objects are assigned. Take this:

```py
>>> a, b = 257, 257
>>> id(a)
140640774013296
>>> id(b)
140640774013296
```

But when you do:

```py
>>> a = 258
>>> b = 258
>>> id(a)
140410944685744
>>> id(b)
140410944685872
```

Note that the ids are different, the same doesn't apply to tuples where a new object is created each time.